# React Native Project won't build on expo or on avd

Tags: react-native, expo

I just got a react native project and I am trying to run it. When I run:
`react-native run-android`
, this is my output.

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in C:\Users\oriont\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\oriont\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\oriont\dev\proj\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\oriont\dev\proj\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (C:\Users\oriont\dev\proj\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

I have followed all of the directions on the facebook getting started page, but this error keeps popping up. When I run it, I have my AVD running, which is on Android 9. From there, I tried to accept the licenses.

```
C:\Users\oriont\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager.bat --licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 5 more
```

And I don't know what to do from here. I tried expo and it was another rabbit hole... Someone please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK**

Tick the latest Android versions, click Apply.

It's at this point where Android will ask you to agree to its license(s) and the updated version(s) will be installed.

[From Here GitHub](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1726#issuecomment-279164447)

Answer (score 1):

I read an answer (Thank you) but it sadly didn't work. I now think that the licenses aren't the problem anymore. I had realized that the project wanted android 27 and I had android 28 installed, so I tried downgrading to android 27. That didn't work, so I just upgraded (I think) the project to android 28 by changing ext in android/build.gradle to:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

and add this to android in android/app/build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
}
```

I also had java 10.0.2 installed and I downgraded to java 8. (not sure if that made a difference)

Anyways I hope this helps people get their old projects up to date!